Paying money to choose the box with $100
This is a question from Mark Joshi's book. The questions goes as following:

Let's play a game. There are 4 sealed boxes. There is $100$ in one box and the others are empty. A player can pay $X$ to open a box and take contents as many times as they like. Assuming this is a fair game, what is the value of $X$

Now, I am thinking about another variation of this question:

What should be the value of $X$ for which the player would not want to open the second box after he opens the first.

My attempt:
$P_1$ = Payoff from opening the first box
$\implies P_1 = 
\begin{cases}
  100-X & {\text{if he finds the money}} \\
  -X & {\text{otherwise}}
\end{cases}
$
Then,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{E}[P_1] &= (100-X)\cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{finds the money}] + (-X)\cdot \mathbb{P}[\text{does not find the money}]\\
&= (100-X) \frac{1}{4} + (-X)\frac{3}{4} \\
&= 25 - X
\end{align}
Similarly, we can find the expected payoff if he goes for the second box. Three possible outcomes:

First box has the money(then he does not go for the second one)
First is empty, Second Box has the money
Both are empty

So, if $P_2$ is the payoff from opening two boxes, then:
\begin{align}
  \mathbb{E}[P_2] &= (100-X)\frac{1}{4} + (100-2X)\frac{3}{4}\frac{1}{3} + (-2x)\frac{3}{4}\frac{2}{3} \\
&= (100-X)\frac{1}{4} + (100-2X)\frac{1}{4} + (-4x)\frac{1}{4} \\
&= 50 - \frac{7}{4}X
\end{align}
He wouldn't go for the second box if the expected future payoff is less than his current payoff (or expected current payoff? I think the former!). If we consider expected current payoff, then the condition becomes:
\begin{align}
50 - \frac{7}{4}X &\leq 25 - X\\
\implies X \geq \frac{100}{3}
\end{align}
Or if we use his worst payoff in opening 1 box, the condition for not playing further becomes:
\begin{align}
50 - \frac{7}{4}X &\leq -X\\
\implies X \geq \frac{200}{3}
\end{align}
Which one is correct? Also, I have a feeling that to calculating optimal stopping, we need to play till the end (till 4 boxes and not just 2) and then construct the inequality.

Playing just once (or just twice, or just three times) makes no sense, because the expectation of your future winnings increases as the number of boxes decreases. (Most obviously, it is never right to quit playing after missing three times!) Put another way, if it is right to play at all, then it is right to play after losing once, twice, or three times.
So you just need to calculate your expected winnings from playing until you find the money. This is
$$\frac14(100-X)+\frac14(100-2X)+\frac14(100-3X)+\frac14(100-4X)=100-\frac52X$$
So the critical value is $X=40$. Below this, you don't play; above this, you play until you find the money.
